# How do multimaps internally handle duplicate keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, multimap

With maps, I can understand it being implemented as a binary search tree (a red/black tree, for example) and the time complexity of it.

But with multimaps, how are key collisions handled internally? Is it that a list is maintained for all the nodes with same keys? Or some other handling is undertaken. I came across a situation where I could use either a `map<int,vector<strings>>` or a `multimap<int,string>` and would like to know the tradeoffs.

Comment: Is your question what specific underlying mechanism is used to handle collisions, or whether to use a `map` with `vector` keys or a `multimap`? Those are actually pretty different questions.

Comment: I wanted to know the specific internal implementation of multimap...

Comment: @basav Different compilers might have implemented it differently. Just to let you know. There are no specific constraints on how to implement them implied by the C++ standard.

Comment: How do i decide if a map of vector of strings makes more sense or a multimap of strings from time complexity point of view for insert and find??

Comment: @mostruash Interestingly, the spec's restrictions actually disallow lots of potential implementations. It's fun to work backwards from them and see what could be allowed and what couldn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ spec doesn't give a specific implementation for `std::multimap`, but instead gives requirements on how fast the operations on `std::multimap` should be and what guarantees should hold on those operations. For example, `insert` on a `multimap` needs to insert the key/value pair into the `multimap` and has to do so in a way that makes it come after all existing entries with the same key. That has to work in time O(log n), and specifically amortized O(1) if the insertion occurs with a hint and the hint is the spot right before where the element should go. With just this information, the `multimap` could work by having a red/black tree with many nodes, one per key, or it could be an red/black tree storing a `vector` of values for each key. (This rules out an AVL tree, though, because the rotations involved in an AVL tree insertion don't run in amortized O(1) time. However, it also permits things like 2-3-4 trees or deterministic skiplists).

As we add more requirements, though, certain implementations get ruled out. For example, the `erase` operation needs to run in amortized constant time if given an iterator to the element to erase. That rules out the use of a single node with a key and a `vector` of values, but it doesn't rule out a single node with a key and a doubly-linked list of values. The `iterator` type needs to be able to dereference to a `value_type`, which needs to match the underlying `allocator`'s `value_type`. This rules out the possibility that you could have individual nodes in a red/black tree with a single key and a linked list of values, since you couldn't obtain a reference to a `value_type` that way.

Overall, the restrictions are such that *one permissible implementation* is a red/black tree with one node per key/value pair, though others may be possible as well. Other ideas - like using an AVL tree, or coalescing values for a given key into a `vector` or `list` - aren't possible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: working backwards from spec and figuring  out what fits in would be a great way to learn stl .